# Disappearing dropbox icon, can't uninstall and reinstall

Tags: dropbox

My dropbox icon from the top bar has disappeared. I have tried to uninstall and reinstall as suggested in an answer to someone with a similar problem but sudo apt-get remove dropbox gets the reply "virtual packages such as dropbox can't be removed". Then I tried sudo apt-get remove dropbox; rm -rvf ~/.dropbox ~/.dropbox-dist (from the dropbox site)which removed some items but not dropbox itself. What do I do? I am using 12.04 and am new to ubuntu.
I still have the launcher icon and the folder but changes/new files don't upload automatically.

Comment: can you remove/reinstall it from software center?

Comment: First could you be more precise about the version of ubuntu you are using (Are you running 12.04 or 14.04 or ...) and the graphic environnement (unity, gnome, kde ...)? Anyway, I just the afternoon trying to fix a similar problem. After a few "miss and try", here is my solution: Ubuntu 12.04 (precise), gnome classic.
My version of dropbox was quite old and I received a mail from the dropbox company advisng me to upgrade.
I created a "/etc/apt/sources.list.d/dropbox.list"as advised [on "ubuntuupdates"](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/dropbox?dist=precise) I don't want dropbox to start with my

Answer (score 0):

I run Ubuntu 14.0.4 and also have the issue where the icon doesn't show by default/from the install I have to run the following:

```
sudo apt-get install libappindicator1
```